# Index and query Unique Key URL Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

i indexed a collection of archived websites for querying using solr. As unique key i use the URL's of the sites. What i would like to do is to use the url field in filter queries to limit the search to a certain domain when needed. For example i want to query for "Barack Obama", but limit the results to the "whitehouse.gov" domain. Sounds like a pretty basic use case to me, however searches on the URL field do not return any results at all. Here is my config (schema.xml):

```
 .
 .
 .
 <field name="collection" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="content" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
 <field name="date" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="digest" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="length" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="segment" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="site" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="title" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
 <field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="url" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 .
 .
 .

<!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. 
  Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
-->
 <uniqueKey>url</uniqueKey>
```

And here is my query (simplified):

```
http://mysolrserver.com:8983/solr/select/?q=content:Barack+Obama&fq=url:whitehouse.gov
```

The query analyzer tells me, that my query should match:

[image: screenshot solr analysis]

Does anyone have an idea why this is not working? I highly appreciate any hints i can get! Thanks alot guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fq=url:whitehouse.gov` filtering should work.

However I see the problem with the query `q=content:Barack+Obama`.
Whats your default search field ??
Does removing the query component and using `q=*:*` return results for you.  ??

`q=content:Barack+Obama` query would actually result into a query like `content:barack defaultsearchfield:obama`
As the default search field would not have obama this would not result in any results.

Comment: Thanks, that solved part of my problem!!however, the behaviour of queries on the URL field does not match with what i see on the analyzer (see the attached image). I only get results when using wildcard search: fq=url:*whitehouse.gov*. This works pretty well though so that's fine with me. I'm now trying to figure out how to limit the search result to multiple urls: q=Barack+Obama+url:(*whitehouse.gov*%20OR%20*foxnews.com*). The result i get from that is different to just q=Barack+Obama, however the results do not only contain the desired subset but also results from multiple other sites...

Comment: you can try fq=url:(whitehouse.gov OR foxnews.com)